Multiple the same error logging in Application Insights if code is executed by trigger via Azure Function
I have an Azure Function Time Trigger which is run each minute to recalculate some state - in other word the code is rerun each minute to calculate something.
The problem I am facing is that if I have a error in this code, for example NullReferenceException etc. This error will be duplicated N times, where N is count of executions by trigger, it leads to thousands of errors in Azure Application Insights but of course it is still the same "first" error which should be fixed.
I would like to logging such error once just to have: clean and understandable log and looking for a good way to do it, ideally, out of the box in Azure. Are there any good practises?

The idea I prepared is -> set the hash/key unique for my error + business logic key to identify the error, for example take into account the data: NullRefException for entity, with Id = 2 and set it into dictionary in SingletonService and check by key in particular handler to log it or not(if already logged).
The problem of this scenario is that I need to implement the key/hash calculation and detect different kind of errors which is not ideal. Also there are plenty of other variants of this idea(change service to storage etc.).

I believe it can be resolved via Azure Application Insights ideally because this service can already groups and detects the error, but I can not find good approach/example how to implement it.
I would appreciate if you can give me the way how to do it.


Any others good practices? Thanks in advance.

The error is not multiplied. When an Azure Function throws/encountering an exception, it will retry the function automatically by default. If I remember correctly the default is like 5 or 10 times bevor it will stop retrying.
This behavior can be configured, please see the documentation for your used language here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=fixed-delay%2Cisolated-process%2Cnode-v4%2Cpython-v2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#max-retry-counts

thanks for the answer, what if when I execute a code, for instance, I try to get entity with Id = 1 and it constantly fails with NRE/NotFound/ETC., but I have time trigger 1 minute and turn off retry or reduced retry to 1 time, looks like it will write the error each minute, right, because the record I am getting still does not exist?

If the retry count is set to 0 or 1 (not sure what disabled is, please look at the docs) it should execute the function exactly once. So, in case you have the not found exception. Every minute would throw the error. Alternatively, handle the exception and do not throw (if expected). If the function completes successfully no retry will be triggered. Even if you log exceptions. Only "throw"  will cause that retry

ok, I plan to use retry policy + write service with collection(dictionary key-value) of logged exception(singleton) where I am going to check if exception should be logged again and how it should be logged. Also if something is critical and non expected for me and my code I will handle it in global handle(function level as described in article) where if needed will throw again for me and retry. What do you think, is it good strategy?

I am not sure what language you are using. But you can just log the error as error. That is not an issue. Just avoid unhandled exceptions/do not throw exceptions then it will not retry
